# MySQL Query form data

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a php form that when submitted sends form values into a MySQL Database named "Hotel" in a table named "Reservations" that has one column titled "Form". In the "Form" column, each form field is enclosed within {} and fields are separated by commas. Here is what the data looks like in the "Form" column:

```
[{"id":"1","translation":"Token","value":"123456789"},
 {"id":"2","translation":"Name","value":"John Smith"}]
```

Desired MySQL Query Result: I want to grab each "translation" and "value" in my query and have them put into separate columns. Column 1 title "Token", Column 2 title "Name" then list the values below each

```
--------------------------
| Token     | Name       |
--------------------------
| 123456789 | John Smith |
--------------------------
```

I have never run into this kind of data in a column before so I am unsure how to create the query. I'm thinking substring perhaps? Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if more information is need from me to help process the request.

Comment: The data in the form column has the type string. It appears to be JSON, which you cannot pre-process with MySQL. You have to fetch the data from the column as is, and then, on the PHP backend, parse it using `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 1):

The form column has data format in json.
Simply fetch the column value and use php function 
$result = json_decode(data);
Now $result holds the data in array format.
Use for each to iterate the array and fetch each value.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's take the JSON string that's in the `Form` column and turn it into an array with `json_decode()`. Assuming you've already retrieved the value from the `Form` column and assigned it to the variable `$form`:

```
$form = json_decode($form,true);
```

Next, we'll retrieve the `Token` value and the `Name` value:

```
$token = $form[0]["value"];
$name = $form[1]["value"];
```

Note: This assumes that 'token' always occurs first in the 'form' string, and that 'name' always occurs second.

Comment: Within this same 'json_decode()' am I also converting it to a **stdclass object** ? I believe I can then insert the extracted values into a new MySQL table. I'm new to JSON so bear with me as i learn :)

Comment: When the second parameter is set to `true` (`json_decode($form,true)`), you are **not** converting it to an object. By leaving that second parameter out (`json_decode($form)`), or by setting it to `false`, you **would** be converting it to an object.

Comment: ...And I'm happy to "bear with you as you learn" -- that's what SO is for. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can it do like this:

Samples to get the Values:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('[{"id":"1","translation":"Token","value":"123456789"},{"id":"2","translation":"Name","value":"John Smith"}]',
                      '^.*"translation":"Token","value\":"([0-9]+)".*$','\\1') AS Token;
```

RESULT: 123456789

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('[{"id":"1","translation":"Token","value":"123456789"},{"id":"2","translation":"Name","value":"John Smith"}]',
                      '^.*"translation":"Name","value\":"(.*)".*$','\\1') AS Name;
```

RESULT: John Smith

To Update the Table:

```
update TABLENAME set
  TOKENFIELD = REGEXP_REPLACE(JSONFIELD,{"id":"2","translation":"Name","value":"John Smith"}]',
                          '^.*"translation":"Token","value\":"([0-9]+)".*$','\\1'),
  NAMEFIELD = SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(JSONFIELD,{"id":"2","translation":"Name","value":"John Smith"}]',
                          '^.*"translation":"Name","value\":"(.*)".*$','\\1');
```

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite the Json decode function? ;)

Comment: sorry, my mistake :-) . Is there a function in MySQL for JSON. In The Example i want to show how to update the complete Table. Its only a Sample, When the Values are in PHP there many better ways. Thanks for your comment